# Error with async code design. UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT],

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, express, azure-blob-storage

I am facing an error with node/express. I am assuming the issue is with my asynchronous code design.

**Output:**
Success in container

**Expected Output:**
Success in container..
Success in Uploading...

**Error**: (node:18364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()

DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

**Code:**

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const AuthReq = require("../middleWare/AuthReq");
require("dotenv").config();
const Azure_Storage_Connection_String = process.env.Azure_Connection_String;
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

const Router = express.Router();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

Router.post("/profile", AuthReq, upload.single("profile"), async (req, res) => {
  const file = req.file;

  const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(
    Azure_Storage_Connection_String
  );

  const containerName = req.user._id;

  const ContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

  try {
    const containerResponse = await ContainerClient.create();
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send("Error while sending image");
  }

  res.send("Success in container");

  const contentType = file.mimetype;

  const filePath = file.path;

  const blobName = file.filename + contentType;

  const blockBlobClient = ContainerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

  try {
    const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(filePath);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send("Error while sending image");
  }

  res.send("Success in Uploading...");
});

module.exports = Router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `res.send` more than once per request, because one request has only one response. I assume that you want to send a "two-part" response, so that the user first sees "Success in container" and then (a few seconds later) "Success in Uploading ...".

Node.js will send the response in two "chunks" if you use

```js
res.write("Success in container");
...
res.end("Success in Uploading...");
```

(See also the explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70774152/16462950).)

Comment: Thanks alot it worked for me! Have an amazing day :)