# Show loading screen until data is ready in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using puppeteer to scrape a job website. Everything is working so far.

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {text: 'This is the index page'});  
})
```

On submit the user gets redirected to an ejs file

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" class="submit" id="city-input" placeholder="Submit City">
        <button type="submit" onclick="submitCity()">Submit</button>
    </div>

</body>
```

script.js

```
function submitCity() {
    const city = document.getElementById('city-input').value;
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/germany/' + city
    window.location.href = url;
    console.log(city);
}
```

index.js

```
app.get('/api/germany/:key', async (req, res) => {
  const city = req.params.key;

  const data = await scraper.scrapeData(city);
  await db.updateDB(data);
  
  await res.render('result', { data: data });
})
```

So when the user clicks on submit it can take about 1-2 minutes until the result page is ready. I want to add a loading page/information until the data is scraped and ready to send.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fetch` to make the request in the background:

```
function submitCity() {
    const city = document.getElementById('city-input').value;
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/germany/' + city
    const response = await fetch(url); // make initial request
    const data = await response.json(); // wait for response body, then parse as json
    console.log(data);
}
```

And on the server, just return the data to the request:

```
app.get('/api/germany/:key', async (req, res) => {
  const city = req.params.key;

  const data = await scraper.scrapeData(city);
  await db.updateDB(data);
  
  return res.json(data);
});
```

Comment: An alternative approach is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70774152/16462950).