# JS fetch should do action on server write

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, vuejs3

Given is the following node stack:

- Client (VUE) (8080)
- Server (express.js) (3000)

The client sends a get to a server route, inside the server route a task is running that takes some time but could easily been mapped because server is working over an array of data.
Is it possible that the server can send a response (write?) which triggers an action on client side?

I've tried the following that "works" when checking the network tab in chrome but i don't know how i can trigger an update on each "write" in my client's fetch because there just nothing happens till "end" is reached.
target would be to show a counter "doing action n of x" that got updated on each write

```
server.mjs:
...
server.get('/action', async (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
// Just to test:
    res.write(JSON.stringify({current: 0, total: 0, status: 'pending'}));
    setTimeout(() => {res.write(JSON.stringify({current: 2, total: 0, status: 'pending'}));},1000);
    setTimeout(() => {res.write(JSON.stringify({current: 3, total: 0, status: 'pending'}));},2000);
    setTimeout(() => {res.write(JSON.stringify({current: 4, total: 0, status: 'pending'}));},3000);
    setTimeout(() => {res.write(JSON.stringify({current: 5, total: 0, status: 'pending'}));},4000);
res.end()
...
```

```
client.js (JS part in vue component)
...
const requestOptions = {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": this.authKey,
            "Save-As": this.saveAs,
            "UUID": this.uuid,
            "Name": this.name
          }
        };
fetch(url, requestOptions)
            .then(response => {
              return response.json()
            })
            .then((data) => {
              console.log(data)
              this.downloadLink = data.url
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error(error);
              this.showError("Backend not reachable")
            });
      },
...
```

As i can see "write" is the only solution where it is possible to send updates to the client but how to handle it then?

Comment: You'll want to look into *websockets*.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/70774152/16462950

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i‘ve solved it by using socket.io in my project. thanks for the hint!