How do you render HTML with initial data first and then again, when finalised data is received (node.js+fastify+Handlebars in Glitch.com)?
I have a minimal app built on top of a Glitch.com default template that uses node.js, fastify and Handlebars.
The user presses a button that has a simple <a href="?generate=now"> style format, then the fastify get route picks that up in fastify.get("/", async function (request, reply), generates one <h2> tag with content and returns it to index.hbs using return reply.view("/src/pages/index.hbs", params); that in turn renders it at {{{content}}}.
All this is working flawlessly, but the thing is, a first version of the content that would already be helpful to the user, is generated very quickly, whereas the final version takes a few seconds (waiting for certain api calls and such).
But I can't figure out a way to return the initial version of the content to index.hbs for rendering without effectively preventing the returning and rendering of the final version of the content.
There must be a simple standard/best practise method for this, but I can't seem to find it by googling, fastify documents or ai help.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773740/i-am-trying-to-render-a-page-based-upon-information-from-an-eventemitters-event

It turns out I just wasn't getting the philosophy of node.js workflow.
Instead of trying to get two distinct results from one get call, I ended up chaining the calls so that the information needed for the 2nd round was passed to frontend hashed and then back to backend for the final iteration.
Alternatively, I could have saved the preliminary data in backend and referenced it in the second get call, so that the result couldn't have been tampered with by changing the url, but for my purposes, hashing the data for frontend was good enough. This referencing workflow would have made session control a necessity, so that different users' results wouldn't get mixed, and that would have been overkill for my little wordplay app.
